# Trees made with Unity's Tree Editor have 2 sides: 1 bright and 1 normal

Tags: unity, shaders

[image]

**(The directional light lits the side shown at the right side of the picture.)**

I tried changing **shaders**, but that just makes the bright side fully dark.

I tried changing **Ambient Occlusion** but that make the normal side fully dark, and the bright side normal.

I use the "**Green Forest**" (free) asset from the Unity Store.

Currently it uses the "**Hidden/Nature/Tree Creator Leaves Optimized**" shader.

Some types of trees got fixed by **turning off AO**, and setting **shadow strength to 0** both at the **shader** and at the **Tree** component, but for example the tree on the picture can't be fixed for some reason.

One type got fixed by setting its shader to "**Tree Creator Leaves Fast**". But that way shadows "float" around the leaves.

Why does this happen?

Comment: This looks similar to the lighting effect you describe in [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/close/83366). I'd recommend deleting the question about lighting appearance from that question if you're going to ask about it separately here.

Comment: Well similar, but not the same. And since then tree creator trees aren't static. So don't know why this error popped up. But closed that question anyway, thanks.